# Pyspark reduce will take in some functions, not others

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm running Python 2.7 on a jupyter notebook. I have the following pyspark RDD object:

```
file_rdd.collect()

[(u'Jane', 2),
 (u'Jane', 1),
 (u'Pete', 20),
 (u'Tyler', 3),
 (u'Duncan', 4),
 (u'Yuki', 5),
 (u'Duncan', 6),
 (u'Duncan', 4),
 (u'Duncan', 5)]
```

When I run `file_rdd.values().reduce(max)`, I get `20`. However, when I run `file_rdd.values().reduce(sum)`, I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-eb9dd2b679d4> in <module>()
----> 1 file_rdd.values().reduce(sum)

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in reduce(self, f)
    800             yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
    801 
--> 802         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    803         if vals:
    804             return reduce(f, vals)

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
    774         """
    775         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 776             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    777         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    778 

/Users/zacharythomas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/zacharythomas/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 30.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 30.0 (TID 59, localhost): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 800, in func
    yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1916)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1930)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:911)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor42.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 167, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 800, in func
    yield reduce(f, iterator, initial)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

Why is that? When I run `file_rdd.values().reduce(lambda x, y: x+y)` I get the desired result `50`.

Someone suggested to me this is because sum needs an iterable object, whereas `.reduce` wants binary operations. That doesn't explain why `max` works though, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, "someone" from the last paragraph is quite right ;-)

`reduce` wants binary operations and `max` is one of them:

```
>>> max(1,2)
2
```

but `sum` is not:

```
>>> sum(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

By looking into [operator module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) you can find `add` binary operator:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> add(1,2)
3
>>> file_rdd.values().reduce(add)
50
```